# Debug Assertion Failed (Dynamic Type Variable)

Tags: c++, assertions

My code compiles as such, but I can't figure out why I keep getting this error that tells me that the "Debug Assertion Failed". Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Bag
{
int k;
};


int main () 
{ 
   int *p1; 
   int *p2;
   char p3;

   //k = 100; // Assigns variable of type bag to 100

   p1 = new int; // Variables created using the new operator are called dynamic variables
   p2 = new int;  


   *p1 = 30;
   *p2 = 50;
    p3  = 'K';

   *p1 = *p1 + *p2; 
    p1 = p2;

   cout << "The sum of the two pointers is = " << *p1 << endl; 

   delete p1;
   delete p2;                // Delete the dynamic variable p1 and return the memory occupied by p1 to the freestore to be reused. 

   system ("Pause");
   return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're getting the Debug Assertion Failed at that line:

```
delete p2;
```

The problem here is that you set  "p1 = p2", so both pointers are pointing to the memory location containing the integer "50". After that you delete the pointer p1 which means UN-allocating the memory location containing the integer "50".

At that point p2 is undefined and trying to delete it will result in debug assertion failed error.